# Estimator for Range (Length of Stay )

Tags: nonparametric, order-statistics, range

I have sample data ad I want to test the claim that the mean length of stay is 7 days. Data is give as pairs ( Arrival Date, Departure Date) , each date given as the nth day of the year, e.g., Jan 3 is give as 3, February 1 is given as 32, etc.
But I don't have a clear idea of the distribution of the stay data

My idea is to use some sort of estimator for the range, using order statistics , finding the distribution for  Y:= Max Departure - Min Departure. This last is standard if the distribution of the sample data is known. Conversely, we can use (ordered) sample data to estimate the distribution.

So I'm stuck here. Do I compare the ( distribution of the ) ordered statistics to those of several distributions, do I do a bootstrap, or do I use a non-parametric estimator for the range?

Comment: It seems to me like you're overthinking this.. Why can't you just compute $\text{length-of-stay} = \text{departure-date} - \text{arrival-date} + 1$? That would you give you length of stay for each guest, and then you can test your claim that the mean length of stay is $7$ days using standard methods. What am I missing here?

Comment: @knrumsey : Doesn't the t-test, which would apply here, assume normality of the population data? So I'd need a non-parametric test, an area that I'm not too familiar with.

Comment: I have added a response to address the question and this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the $t$-test *does* assume normality of the sample, it is (as intended) fairly robust to this assumption for large samples, due to the CLT.

Assuming you have a fairly large sample without any extreme outliers, this is probably the easiest path forward. To validate the assumptions, I recommend looking at the bootstrap distribution of the sample mean. That process would look something like this:

```
# SIMULATE DATA
#' Note: This data is definitely not normally distributed
n <- 300
length_of_stay <- rpois(n, 1.5)
B <- 10000
boot_samples <- rep(NA, B)
for(i in 1:B){
  ind <- sample(n, n, replace=TRUE)
  length_of_stay_new_sample <- length_of_stay[ind]
  boot_samples[i] <- mean(length_of_stay_new_sample)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)
hist(boot_samples, 
     freq=F, xlab="Mean Length of Stay")
curve(dnorm(x, mean(boot_samples), sd(boot_samples)), 
      add=TRUE, lwd=3, col='darkorange')
car::qqPlot(boot_sample, pch=16, cex=0.5)
```

[image]

This plot demonstrates that the *sampling distribution of the sampling mean* is very close to a normal distribution, as promised by the CLT. Thus in this setting, you would be able to conduct a t-test without worrying about the underlying distribution of the data.

On the other hand, if you repeat this process and find a large deviation from normality, then you may need to look for alternative options.

Comment: Fair enough, I had ignored the clt , which kicks in at around n=30.

Comment: @MSIS, Careful! The $n=30$ rule is one of the silliest/most dangerous pseudo-rules ever invented. There are may many distributions for which the CLT won't "kick in" for much much larger than $30$. For an interesting example, see the *half $t$ distribution* with $2+\epsilon$ degrees of freedom for small $\epsilon$. It is much safer to look at the bootstrap distribution (or something similar) like I show above.

Comment: Is that code R, Python?

Answer (score 2):

From the problem, you will certainly assume that the patients are independent. You thus get one LOS per patient and these are assumed independent.

You aim at testing the hypothesis that the mean LOS in the population is 7. Under the independence assumption of the patients, provided that your sample size is reasonably large, you can use a t-test (and thus compare the mean of the observed LOS with 7). Otherwise, you can do a non-parametric test assessing whether the centrality parameter of the distribution is seven. The sign test is the simplest one that comes to mind.

I do not see what would be the point in estimating the range given the goal that you state. Do not hesitate to elaborate on this.

Comment: Doesn't the t-test assume the normality of the population being sampled